# Writing online XML file to textbox

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

I am using a PHP script to generate xml files. I want to write the data in the XML file to a `Textblock` in my Windows Phone 8 App.
When I debug, I get an error which is not caught my the `catch`. A print screen of the error: http://i811.photobucket.com/albums/zz38/JelleK1996/errorxml1_zps20df0a45.png
What is wrong?

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace xml1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://cocktailpws.net23.net/requests/get_cocktail.php?id=10") as HttpWebRequest;
                request.BeginGetResponse(r =>
                {
                    var reponse = request.EndGetResponse(r);
                    //XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(reponse.GetResponseStream());
                    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(reponse.GetResponseStream());
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        switch (reader.NodeType)
                        {
                            case XmlNodeType.Element: // Het knooppunt is een element.
                                Console.Write("<" + reader.Name);
                                Console.WriteLine(">");
                                break;
                            case XmlNodeType.Text: //De tekst in elk element weergeven.
                                tb1.Text = tb1.Text + reader.Value + "\r\n";
                                Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
                                break;
                            case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Het einde van het element weergeven.
                                Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
                                Console.WriteLine(">");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }, null);
            }
            catch (Exception myExc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(myExc.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605166/windows-phone-8-threading-invalid-cross-thread-access

Comment: @qwr uh ok. But I don't see where I should add that in my code and how.. Yea, I'm new to C#

Comment: check answer. but for the error there are many answers devoted to it so I just  answered only considering your situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you have not got `try catch` block inside lambda function. Thats why you  cant handle error

Secondly how to solve:
change :

```
tb1.Text = tb1.Text + reader.Value + "\r\n";
```

to

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>  {
      tb1.Text = tb1.Text + reader.Value + "\r\n";
    });
```

Thirdly,
I Believe you need rewrite your xml loop, Cause  your code is inefficent way. It will call text change if there are many texts.So  build string then after loop  call text change

```
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
...
//inside xml loop:
   res.AppendLine(reader.Value);
...
//after loop:
  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>  {
          tb1.Text =  res.ToString();
        });
```

And check this to see what was error. or search invalid thread call 
 [invalid thread call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605166/windows-phone-8-threading-invalid-cross-thread-access)

Comment: And if I only want the contents of the `Node` named name, how should I loop through the `Response`? Because the XmlReader I'm using, will loop through all nodes..

Comment: @JelleKerkstra actually xmlreader is the fastest and most time  you have to loop like you did. for simple example check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @JelleKerkstra another nice options to use xmlDom or linq to XML. but they are not as fast as xmlreader

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must access tb1 from the UI thread, so I would suggest trying to use a statement similar to this:

```
case XmlNodeType.Text: //De tekst in elk element weergeven.
{
    tb1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        tb1.Text = tb1.Text + reader.Value + "\r\n";
    });
    Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
}
break;
```